# Python with MongoDB documents iteration is very slow vs all documents as local variable in local RAM

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I made a script that transform information from a big number of documents from one collection into another collection with some new keys and values.

In mongodb I have **250k documents.**
Each document structure is something like this:

```
{_id:1, city:'City 1', population:200, happinessRating:20, otherRating:5, ...}

{_id:2, city:'City X', population:3000, happinessRating:15, otherRating:7, ...}
```

I made a python function that transform each document with some complex math formulas in another document with new keys and values that I insert in another collection.

**The purpose of the script:**

> Get unique(distinct) cities that have more than 500 population, I have
> a total of 1300 cities.

> Loop throw each City, get all documents that
> have that specific City as value for city key (example: all documents
> that have "city:'City 1'") and  apply the python function for each
> document and then insert that new transformed document into another
> collection.

**Scenario 1:**

> I take all the documents in one query from mongodb to a local variable
> (so I have everything in RAM memory)

> I write some python code to make
> a dictionary with the name of each unique city as key and his
> documents as a list [].

> I loop the dictionary, apply the function,
> insert the documents to the new collection.

> Final new collection documents: 250k documents

**Execution time: 4 minutes**

**Advantage:** very fast executioin time

**Disadvantage:** it takes more than 20GB of RAM and it's not scalable when the number of documents will be 1M documents instead of 250k documents

**Scenario 2:**

> I made a mongodb aggregation (or use distinct function) so I get a
> list of all unique cities names that have more then 500 population.

> So now I have a list of 1300 cities. Same as Scenario 1.

> Now I made a loop and for each city I get the mongodb documents of that specific
> city, apply the function and then insert the documents to the new collection.

> Final new collection documents: 250k documents

**Execution time: 72 minutes**

**Advantage:** don't need too much RAM, less than 500MB

**Disadvantage:** it takes a lot of time to finish the execution

**THE PROBLEM**

So I don't understand why this is happening.

In Scenario 1, I made just **1 query to mongodb** so I have everything in a python variable in my RAM memory.

In Scenario 2, I made **1301 queries to mongodb**, 1 to get the distinct unique cities list, and 1 query for each city

MongoDB is a local server, so the connection is very fast. In Scenario 1 it takes less than 20s to get all documents to the local variable in python.

Another important information is that the funcion that transform each document is very complex and I can't use MongoDB Aggregation to transform it so I need to do it throw that python function.

**I hope I have explained myself well.**

**Any suggestion or advice on how to go ahead with the project is welcome. Thanks**

Comment: What do you mean by "very complex"? Can you provide it? Maybe you can do a mix. Or consider [Bulk Write Operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/)

Comment: Aggregation queries allow perform distinct operation and also allows looping thru the distinct documents and apply some logic on it, and write the result to another collection. All this as a single operation on the database server. This may give a better performance.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit well the script is over 1k lines of code, I simplified the example to explain the problem. After executing the script for each document there are 300 new fields. What surprises me is that it takes more than 1 hour to make 1301 queries to mongodb. Shouldn't it be almost as fast as scenario 1?

we are also investigating the world of working with large amounts of data and creating new indexes and we are still in development and testing and I do better in python since in mongodb I started less than a week ago.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit For example, one of the fields is calculated by ordering a group of cities by a date, creating a counter if it meets certain conditions, then the date is changed in reverse order, other indices are counted again and then a mathematical operation is done to create a percentage.

Comment: I will investigate the aggregation queries better, and Bulk Write Operations maybe can improve something but the python script has taken me more than 1 month of development being comfortable programming in python. The aggregation queries would not solve 100% of the fields, and if I only have to calculate one field in python, I need to make a lot of queries to mongodb again.

I would like to understand **why it takes so long if I do a lot of queries to mongodb, that if I only do one, I create everything in ram, and then insert everything back into mongo.**

Comment: Maybe show us just a subset of it. Are you aware of new operator [$setWindowFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)? It may help you. Running just one query is of course fast than running 1300 queries.

Comment: I didn't know it existed: D. i am new to mongo. Thanks, I'm looking at it right now.

And another question, is there a way to make a query that groups the documents by a field?

`db.getCollection("test").aggregate( [ 
    {
        $match: {
            "population": {$gte: 500}, 
        }
    },
    {
        $group : { _id : "$city" , counter: { $sum:1}}
    },
    {
        $sort: {counter: -1}
    },
    {
        $match: {counter: {$gt: 70}}
    }

] )`

Comment: For example, this query returns the cities that have documents with a population greater than or equal to 500, groups them, order them from highest to lowest and only shows those that have more than 70 documents that meet the requirements > = 500.

I could collect the documents of each city as an array in that query and then treat it in loops in an aggregate or Bulk Write Operations query?

Comment: Your query is fine - but you should turn the order of `{ $sort: { counter: -1 } }` and `{ $match: { counter: { $gt: 70 } } }` And please edit your question for such information and put it there instead of a comment. Sorry, your requirements are so generic, it's almost impossible to provide any answer.

Answer (score 1):

This does not provide a real answer but it illustrates the principle to compose dynamic aggregation pipelines, reuse operators and make it clearly arranged:

```
var match = {}
match["$match"] = { a: 1 }

var sort = { b: -1 }

var pipeline = [];
pipeline.push(match);
pipeline.push({ $sort: sort });
pipeline = pipeline.concat({ $skip: 5 }, { $limit: 3 })

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, { allowDiskUse: true })
```

You may give it a try.